# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy..... on struts2 actions

Tags: java, spring, struts2, spring-aop

I'm using spring AOP for the logging. The app works fine if I uncomment these lines

```
@Before("bean(*Action)")
public void logActionEnter(JoinPoint jp) {
    log.info("Entering action: " + jp.getSignature().getName());
}
```

I'm just wondering. This should work, but apparently it doesn't.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy630.login()
    java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1655)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.getActionMethod(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:75)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:47)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

In case you're interesterd, the `login()` method

```
public String login() throws Exception {
    String name = getAuthService().loginUser(username, password);

    if(name == null) {
        setType("not_found");
        return "failed";
    }
    if(name.equals("LOCKED")) {
        setType("is_locked");
        return "failed";
    }
    if(name.equals("LOCKED_LOG")) {
        setType("login_lock");
        return "failed";
    }

    if(name.isEmpty()) {
        setType("auth_failed");
        return "failed";
    }

    if(session.containsKey("user")) return "session-active";

    User user = getAuthService().setUserActiveNow(username);

    session.put("user", username);
    session.put("completeName",name);
    session.put("access", getAuthService().getFunctionAccess(username));
    session.put("loginDate", user.getLastLoginDt());
    session.put("userId", user.getId());

    getAuditLogService().writeLog(username, new Date(), 
            ServletActionContext.getRequest().getRequestURL().toString(), username + ":" + name + " logged in to IVRBO");

    return "success-login";
}
```

**EDIT**: I have also a `validate()` method on this class.

**EDIT**: here's the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- beans here -->

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bdo.ivr" />

</beans>
```

The aspects. I used annotations.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Before("bean(*Action)")
    public void logActionEnter(JoinPoint jp) {
        log.info("Entering action: " + jp.getSignature().getClass() + ": " + jp.getSignature().getName());
    }

    @Before("bean(*Service)")
    public void logServiceEnter(JoinPoint jp) {
        log.info("Entering service: " + jp.getSignature().getClass() + ": " + jp.getSignature().getName());
    }

    @Before("bean(*Dao)")
    public void logDaoEnter(JoinPoint jp) {
        log.info("Entering DAO: " + jp.getSignature().getClass() + ": " + jp.getSignature().getName());
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = 
            "bean(*Service) || bean(*Dao)",
          throwing = "e")
    public void logException(Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception", e);
    } 

}
```

Comment: Check for the appropriate jars...

Comment: @Ashish I have the jars needed. I also applied AOP to the service and DAO layer, and it works. My app only gets broken when I uncomment the code posted above.

Comment: @SciasTwentyThree Can you post a list of jars that you have in your application class path. It could be that you have the jar but you don't have the appropriate version that contains the method your application runtime is looking for or you don't have the jar at all.

Comment: Since the `login()` method is looked up in a `$Proxy` class this method must be present in the `interface` for which the proxy was generated. This failure indicates that this is not the case. This is the low-level information about the problem.

Comment: @Holger My actions do not implement any interface. So what now? I'm new to AOP so I'm finding it really hard to figure this out.

Comment: @Holger However, my actions extend a base action but that base action does not implement any interface.

Comment: Sorry, I can only decode the low-level problem from the stack trace. I have no idea of these AOP implementation. The best you can do is to carefully check your usage of the annotation. It seems that you combine (at least) two things which the framework’s developers have not foreseen to be combined.

Comment: Post your aspect configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring by default proxies your beans with JDK proxies which only implement your class' interfaces, not their actual class. If the `login()` method only appears on the actual class, the proxy won't declare it.

Put `CGLIB` jars on your classpath and set

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

So that Spring uses the actual class type for the proxy.

Comment: I've put `cglib-3.0.jar`. The page now appears, however, it appears that my codes are not executed properly. For instance, `login()` method is actually called but I can't login to my application. The app just brings me back to the login page.

Comment: @SciasTwentyThree Without more details, we can't tell. Have you tried debugging to see what is called and what isn't?

Comment: Sorry, I got it working now. The problem was I misconfigured the bean for the login processing. Thanks!